# React-Native render json from fetch

Tags: json, api, dictionary, react-native, render

I have a fetch returning on ComponentDidMount(). Trying to get the response to render on the page.

I have set the state as follows:

```
this.state = {
  loading: true,
  file: null,
  video: null,
  marks: []
};
```

and my fetch:

```
componentDidMount() {
return fetch('http://10.0.2.2:8080/marks/createMark')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      marks: data.mark
    }, () => {
      console.log(data.mark);
      console.log(this.state.marks);
      // const dataMap = data.mark.map((item) => {
      //   return {
      //     key: item.id,
      //     label: item.mark
      //   };
      // });
    });
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

}

Now my render inside of the return:

```
 const { marks } = this.state;

      <FlatList
        data={marks}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.mark}</Text>}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      />
```

Do I have to map the data then try to render it??

OUTPUT OF console.log(this.state.marks):

```
{ _id: '5b61e47a55a0000aa980fab1', mark: 'ItHe', __v: 0 }
```

The mark is a pseudorandom string that can contain letters and numbers created on the backend

Comment: Can u please share the output of console.log((this.state.marks).

Comment: ok I added the console.log() output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this.state.marks is an object. First, you need to convert it to this form [{}]. You can do the following changes to make it work.

```
fetch('http://10.0.2.2:8080/marks/createMark')
.then(response => response.json())
.then((data) => {

  let marks = [data.mark];  //Add this line

  this.setState({
    loading: false,
    marks: marks    // Change this line
  }, () => {  
       ....
 Rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammed. I really appreciate your help. This is the correct answer but I cannot up-vote because of my low reputation.

Comment: It's my pleasure. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`marks` is an array but you're not sharing what each object in the array looks like. If it's an array of strings, you're good but if it's an object, you'll need to destructure it and pull out the string you're looking to render.

`<Text>{item.mark.someKeyWhoseValueIsAString}</Text`